# radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n!}$

Tags: power-series

> How to find the radius of convergence of the power series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n!}?$$

I don't know how to start !!!

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Hadamard formula?

Comment: Why negetive vote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: If $|z|<1$, $|z|^{n!}\leq|z|^n$, if $|z|>1$ $|z|^{n!}\geq|z|^n$.